# manually handling of transactions with Speedment

Tags: java, speedment

Is it possible to manually handling transactions with Speedment?
I would like to do many inserts or updates in single transaction.

Default behavior of example code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        Entry e = new EntryImpl()
                .setEntrytime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setUserId(janek.getId())
                .setDoor(rnd.nextInt(32))
                .setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        entries.persist(e);
    }
```

is:

```
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Query, SET autocommit=0
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Prepare, INSERT INTO `speed`.`entry` (`id`,`entrytime`,`user_id`,`uid`,`door`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Execute, INSERT INTO `speed`.`entry` (`id`,`entrytime`,`user_id`,`uid`,`door`) VALUES (0,'2017-06-01 15:15:11',14,'e5cab887-2373-4a19-b8e7-cc914c4d41c4',5)
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Close stmt, 
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Query, commit
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Query, SET autocommit=0
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Prepare, INSERT INTO `speed`.`entry` (`id`,`entrytime`,`user_id`,`uid`,`door`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Execute, INSERT INTO `speed`.`entry` (`id`,`entrytime`,`user_id`,`uid`,`door`) VALUES (0,'2017-06-01 15:15:11',14,'79d38492-9952-485f-ab03-ff5654d6c78e',9)
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Close stmt, 
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Query, commit
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Query, SET autocommit=0
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Prepare, INSERT INTO `speed`.`entry` (`id`,`entrytime`,`user_id`,`uid`,`door`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Execute, INSERT INTO `speed`.`entry` (`id`,`entrytime`,`user_id`,`uid`,`door`) VALUES (0,'2017-06-01 15:15:11',14,'ce210b3a-47ac-4c9a-bec9-748a4828843a',13)
2017-06-01T13:15:11, 24, Close stmt,
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can:

```
TransactionComponent transactionComponent =app.getOrThrow(TransactionComponent.class);
TransactionHandler txHandler = transactionComponent.createTransactionHandler();


txHandler.createAndAccept(tx -> {

   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        Entry e = new EntryImpl()
                .setEntrytime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setUserId(janek.getId())
                .setDoor(rnd.nextInt(32))
                .setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        entries.persist(e);
    }

            }
        )
    );
```